# Rails 3.1 and Ruby EE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, upgrade, ruby-enterprise-edition

Since Rails 3.1 strongly recommends that it be installed with Ruby 1.9.2. But what about Ruby Enterprise Edition support? Ruby EE seems to be in the 1.8.x version, so I guess this means that future rails updates won't be working so well with it?

Comment: The need for Ruby EE was to make a faster ruby, for entreprise use.
Ruby 1.9 is already much faster, which removes the need for this VM. You can use directly MRI 1.9, no need for any REE 1.9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's only a recommendation (and I suggest it too), because as you may know, 1.9.2 is the most recent version.

you can still use REE for your 3.1 rails app, but keep in mind that *some day* you'll be forced to switch to a newer ruby interpreter, and it's not a painless task (even if you have a decent test coverage).

if it's about a passenger matter, don't worry, it will work on 1.9.2 too ;)

Comment: That said, Rails 3.x still officially supports 1.8.7, so using that version of REE should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

if you generate new rails 3.1 app on 1.9 it will use new hash syntax, so you will not be able to easily switch to 1.8 later.

example: `config/initializer/session_store.rb` uses new hash syntax

```
YourApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_yourapp_session'
```

Comment: 3.1 uses new hash syntax only if you create your application with ruby 1.9. If you create it with 1.8, hashes will be created the old way.

Comment: This answer is apropos, given that some folks will start by using a more "familiar" Ruby like MRI 1.9, and then try to throw REE at it.

Answer (score 0):

Our large Rails 3.1 app runs very slowly when we migrated it to ruby 1.9.2

We upgraded it rather than creating from scratch, so maybe we did something wrong, but running it with 1.9 is so slow it's unusable, switching to REE make it run nicely again.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to take the plunge and moved my app over to REE. It seems to work the same, a bitter faster in fact. The memory usage seems about the same. The guys from Phusion did an awesome job with the installer :)